# What is the oldest train in the UK still operated regularly for a non-tourism purpose?

Tags: uk, trains, factoids, nostalgia

What can I find the oldest train in the UK still operating regularly, and the train(s) is/are operated for common service but not solely for tourist attraction?

And which route(s) are they serving?

Comment: Sounds strange to ask in Travel SE specifically for a non-tourist activity.

Comment: @gmauch i mean trains used for normal service, not designated for tourist spot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they aren't actually the oldest, but travelling by Northern Rail often makes you feel like you're in a historic artefact.

Comment: @CMaster I think those are escaped buses... They [apparently date from the 80s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacer_%28train%29), they're just well past their initial lifespan :/

Comment: @gmauch. Makes sense to me. If you're interested in trains (many people are!) and want a "real" experience, you want to know which old trains are running standard scheduled services, not tourist trails.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be word-smithed better to show a connection to travel

Comment: @CGCampbell Go ahead and edit it. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO No. It's not my question. While I will (and do) edit questions for spelling and grammar changes, I will never edit the content of a question where my changes will (potentially) modify the meaning or intent behind the question. I would _much prefer_ the OP learn how to formulate a question which is not in any way, questionable as to its topicality. Also, I have noticed a lose/lose here. If I don't point out why I down-vote and/or VtC, there are complaints. If I do, there are complaints.

Comment: All the OP need do is add something like "While traveling in the UK, I would really like to ride on the oldest....." to the beginning. However, if we fix the questions for Him (pun? intended), Him will never learn....

Comment: @CGCampbell OK I understand your `teach a man to fish` approach. I usually fix these questions myself, especially when they've received valid answers as I feel that waiting for the OP to edit themselves sometimes leads to an endless wait. No complaint on my side, IMHO you are right to explain the close vote. I do that too.

Comment: @Him Your last edit renders the question explicitly off-topic for TSE. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that this answer was perfectly correct when written but the trains to which it refers have been replaced with the 484 series built in the mid-1970s. The link to the Wikipedia entry to which this answer refers has now been updated to reflect that.

=========================

I believe that the oldest ones in service right now are on the [Island Line on the Isle of Wight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_Line_Trains), which is part of the South West Trains franchise. Not to be confused with the [Isle of Wight Stream Railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Wight_Steam_Railway), the Island Line is a regular part of the UK rail network run as normal services.

Because of the low ceiling of the Ryde Tunnel, the Island Line has a much smaller loading gauge than the rest of the UK mainline rail network, so has to use different trains. Today, those are [the class 483](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_483), which are [refurbished 1938 London Underground trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_Line_Trains#Rolling_stock)!

As explained in the [wikipedia article on the trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_483)

> The stock is around 75 years old, making it the oldest type in Great Britain to remain in regular service

And they look like this, in their current (returned to historic) colour scheme:

[image: cc-by photo from widnes_road from www.flickr.com/photos/widnes_road/16569159135]

Comment: Why didn't you mention the Bakerloo Line?

Comment: The Bakerloo Line is all run with 1972 stock though, isn't it, so 40 years newer newer than the Island line trains?

Comment: The Bakerloo line just *seems* like it's 70 years old ;)

Comment: Those trains are spring chickens! They're only 43 years old... And older than the northern pacers which CMaster is such a fan of ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It may be touristy, but has regular scheduled operation: the Snaefell Mountain Railway on the Isle of Man.

Comment: If that counts, then the [Hythe Pier train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hythe_Pier#Hythe_Pier_Railway) may be the oldest.  The locomotives were built in 1917 (the carriages may be older), and are primarily used by commuters using the ferry, though I'm sure the odd tourist uses it too.

Answer (score 1):

I was speaking to a guard at Brighton station about how stinky the coastal trains are, and he told me that Old Blue is the oldest train in the country in use today. I'm riding it to work today.

Comment: Does it look like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_303?

Comment: If the wikipedia articles covering train lines around Brighton are up-to-date, it seems that the [Class 313](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_Class_313) is the oldest rolling stock in use there, built in 1976.

Comment: Wikipedia is a thoroughly unreliable source. Look up what happened to the Scottish Wikipedia -- and never use it again for anything again but as a starting point for research but be mindful of citogenesis.

Comment: @chx it's right about the 313s here though. The 313s are now certainly the oldest trains in regular passenger service working National Rail or non-touristy open access services, since the 1938 stock was replaced on the Isle of Wight.